# First %s scanf value get ignore but second %s can store the value

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char i;
    char s;
    printf("Enter first char : ");
    scanf("%s", &i);
    printf("Enter second char : ");
    scanf("%s", &s);
    printf("%c", i);
    printf("%c", s);
}
```

The output turn out only print second scanf value while the first scanf value does not print out.

```
int main()
{
    char i;
    char s;
    printf("Enter first char : ");
    scanf("%c", &i);
    printf("Enter second char : ");
    scanf(" %c", &s);
    printf("%c", i);
    printf("%c", s);
}
```

When change to use %c both scanf value can be print out.

Why does the %s only store the last input while the first get ignored?

Comment: You can't use `%s` in a scanf with a scalar `char` variable.  `%s` writes a string, including a terminating null character, so using the address of a scalar `char` will cause memory corruption.  Either change the `%s`, or else use a `char` array instead.

Comment: so the %s should be for the char s[10] type right?

Comment: Something like that.  Keep in mind that there is no length check, so `char s[10]` would work for strings up to 9 characters long (plus one for the null character).

Comment: does this have any reference about this case? hopefully i can read it up because lecturer teaching us using %s

Comment: You should *never* use a raw `%s`, for exactly the same reason you should never use `gets`.  You need `char s[2]; scanf("%1s", s)` or `char s; scanf("%c", s)`, or do the right thing and stop using scanf completely.  Just do `int s; s = getchar();` and then discard whitespace in a while loop.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%s is to scan string :

```
scanf(" %s",&string);
```

Or

```
 scanf("%s[^\n]",string);
```

%c to scan only one caracter :

```
scanf(" %c",&caracter);
```

in your first code ,if you want to read two string and print them :use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i[150];
    char s[150];
    printf("Enter first char : ");
    scanf("%s[^\n]",i);//scan the first string
    printf("Enter second char : ");
    scanf("%s[^\n]",s);//scan the second string
    printf("%s", i);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", s);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",i[1]);//if you want to print the second caracter in the string i
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",s[0]);//if you want to print the first caracter in the string s
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I know the the %s is used for string with length like your example given. Just having an issue with this because my teacher was teaching me like this with wrong method

Comment: You have `”%s[^\n]”`, which scans a space-delimited string and then looks for an open square bracket, a caret, an arbitrary and possibly empty white space sequence, and a close square bracket, but it probably fails to find those literals.  You probably intended to use `”%[^\n]”`, which is a scan set looking for a sequence of none-newlines.  Note there is no `s` in that, neither before nor after the scan set.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : to scan a string ,which I can use : scanf("%[^\n]s",string); or         scanf("%s[^\n]",string)

Comment: Neither is correct — scan set conversion specifiers do not use `s`.  Both will work, up to a point.  The first looks for a sequence of non-newlines followed by a letter a, which it won't find but it has no way of reporting that failure.  The second will read the first word in the input and then fail (usually) to find the following literal characters.  It has no way of reporting the failure here either.  If you had other conversions after these, you would be able to spot the failure more easily.  Trailing literals can fail to match without there being a way to report the problem.

Comment: Apologies for the bloody-minded spell-mangler that is adamant that ”non” should be ”none”.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Can I use fgets ?

Comment: Yes, if you're careful, you can use `fgets()`.  Remember that `scanf()` will leave a newline in the input, ready to confuse you.  Also, `fgets()` reads and saves the newline if there is room for it.  Using `fgets()` to read lines and then using `sscanf()` to parse the lines is often a good way to work.